# Ruby on Rails - field not recognized by ActiveRecord relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` table for my app which contains the list of all users. This table has a `Boolean field` named `active`.

I have this code to fetch the user:

```
existing_user = User.where("LOWER(email) = ?", auth_hash['info']['email'].downcase)
```

And this is what I get when I do an `existing_user.inspect`:

```
User Load (1.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER(email) = 'biswanath.chandramouli@gmail.com')
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 4, name: "Biswanath Chandramouli", email: "Biswanath.Chandramouli@gmail.com", last_updated_by: "", admin: true, active: true, last_updated_on: nil, created_at: "2018-10-30 08:14:59", updated_at: "2018-10-30 08:14:59"
```

As you can see, `existing_user` has the property `active` available as shown above.

But this code fails:

```
if(!existing_user.active?)
```

The above call throws this error:

```
undefined method `active?' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f0a58b2c500> Did you mean? acts_like?
```

When `existing_user.inspect` shows `active: true`, why does the above call `existing_user.active` fail? Pls help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use `if(!existing_user.first.active?)`. This will work in your case. Where clause returns you an array, not an object. In your case, `existing_user` is an array not an object.

Answer (score 0):

***This answer is off-topic but could save you a lot:***

Every time you call this `existing_user = User.where("LOWER(email) = ?", auth_hash['info']['email'].downcase)`, it's going to downcase all the emails in the table and look for the correct one.

I would suggest to downcase the email before saving the user and add an **index** on it;

```
before_save { self.email = self.email.downcase }
```

and then get the user:

```
user = User.where(email: auth_hash['info']['email'].downcase).first
```

Try this method and you'll see a big difference in the data retrieval (which is now `1.9ms`)